# Windows shell-scripting - 'set variable' does not set current value but takes previous one

Tags: batch-file, window

If I run this script several times it would take previous value to be set.

```
SET /P VALUE_FROM_FILE= < app.pid
echo %VALUE_FROM_FILE%
```

So If I run it first time it prints me `"333"`

Then I go to `app.pid` file and change its content to `"444"`

run this script again, it prints `"333"`

What is the proper way to handle that kind of behavior?

--

**Update:** I've rewrited my script like that to behave properly

```
   for /f %%r in (result.txt) do (
      echo %%r
   )
```

Comment: search for `delayed expansion`

Answer (score 1):

that would only display the first word in each line .. to make it get all text in file use this instead..

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%r in (filename.extension) do (
echo %%r
)
```

that should do .. hope it helps ...